# ng-admin2: Setting the Title of a Page not Included in the Menu

Tags: angular, ng-admin

I need to change the title of a page not included in the sidebar menu when using ng-admin2.  Primarily, when dynamically editing an object and really anytime doing anything with dynamic routing.

Answer (score 0):

First, import `AppState` by adding `import {AppState} from '../app.state';`

Second, make sure you reference it in your constructor:

```js
  constructor(private _state: AppState) {}
```

Third, inside of `ngOnInit()` or in a subsequent function after the constructor, call the `notifyDataChanged` function inside `this._state`, like this:

```js
  this._state.notifyDataChanged('menu.activeLink', {title:"Edit User ${username}..."});
```

Also, to exclude a navigational item from the side menu, just remove the `menu:{title:''}` inside of `data` in  your `pages.routes.ts` file.

I'm sure there's a way to tweak the overall component to be more complete, but in my simple implementation, this worked fine.

So completed code should look something like this:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AppState} from '../app.state';

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-user',
  template: require('./edit-user.html')
})
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit{
  public username : string;

  constructor(private _state: AppState) {
     //if you call notifyDataChanged here, it won't take since it's called again
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._state.notifyDataChanged('menu.activeLink', {title:"Edit User ${username}..."});
  }
}
```